# Routing only Python audio output to virtual recording device

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, jack

I have a python script that's using the gmusicapi and vlc libs to create a media player that takes requests based on text commands entered in a chat/VOIP program. On Windows 10/ in python is there a way to take the audio ONLY coming from the python script and route it to a virtual recording device?

I'm thinking maybe using the JACK lib but i'm not familiar with JACK yet

Essentially what [SoundLeech](http://www.milosoftware.com/en/index.php?body=soundleech.php) does except instead of writing to a file route the audio to a virtual recording device.

Win 10/ Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I personally tried pyAudio, pyAudioAnalyzer and sounddevice

Since you're running python 3.6 and lower you can use pyAudio but I would still recommmend sounddevice ( I find it more flexible and easy to use, but that is just my opinion )

```
py -m pip install sounddevice
```

then in your python code

```
import sounddevice
```

I've been using it mainly to list audio devices and change defaults values and stuff but you should be able to route one to another.
Maybe with:

```
sounddevice.get_stream
```